# Shard key and Azure CosmosDB for MongoDB API

Tags: python, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I created a CosmosDB database that uses MongoDB's Python SDK, let's call the database as `school` and the collection as `students`. While creating the database, the Azure UI asked me to create a shard key for unlimited storage capacity, let's call it `school.students`.

I am using `pymongo` to add the following document:

```
{
  "id": "abc123",
  "name": "jack"
}
```

and the code as:

```py
from pymongo import MongoClient

student_data = {
  "id": "abc123",
  "name": "jack"
}

client = MongoClient("mongodb://...")
db = client["school"]
collection = db["students"]
collection.insert_one(student_data)
```

When I chose the storage with 10GB, I have no problem adding the document, but when I chose the unlimited option with shard key, I get the following error:

```
pymongo.errors.WriteError: document does not contain shard key at 'school.students'
```

Question is, where should I use the shard key? and how to get over this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `shard key` in MongoDB maps to a `partition key` in Cosmos DB. When you create your collection, you're asked to specify a *partition key*, if you create it via the portal. Or you can specify the shard key via MongoDB's command line tool or via code (where it's then called a *shard key*). That shard key must exist in your document.

In your case, your document only contains `id` and `name` (and you can use either of those as your shard key). Alternatively, you can specify an additional property as your shard key. For example, maybe `schoolid`:

```js
student_data = {
  "id": "abc123",
  "name": "jack",
  "schoolid": "school1" 
}
```

When creating your collection, you'd specify `schoolid` as your partition key. At this point, your document-save would work, as you will have a shard key (partition key) included in your document.

In your original example, you specified `school.students` as your shard key. That would require you having a property called `school` with a sub-property called `students` (which I'm guessing doesn't make too much sense to do):

```js
student_data = {
  "id": "abc123",
  "name": "jack",
  "school": {
     "students": ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create the collection via the mongo shell

```
db.runCommand( { shardCollection: "myDb.students", key: { id: "hashed" } } )
```

Comment: I already have a collection from the Azure UI, as `students` and it asked me to create a shard key while creating the collection. But how should I use the shard key?

Comment: You need to create it from the shell, not from the azure ui

Comment: @Sajeetharan - this isn't true. You can absolutely create a collection via the portal (the shard key is called a *partition key* in the portal). The OP's issue is that they specified a partition key (shard key) that doesn't exist in the document they tried inserting. I explained this fully in my answer.

Comment: @DavidMakogon Yes, I agree with your point. What I mentioned here was different. As I remember there was a similar issue earlier when you create from the portal even after including the partition key with MongoDB it does not actually work in the manner as expected. I will try to find the post and paste here, even though I have not tried it

Comment: @Sajeetharan - it's possible there could've been an issue in the past. Before posting my answer, I created a new collection, with partition key, and had no issue connecting via mongo shell and writing/reading docs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Sajeetharan but DavidMakogon answer was what I wanted. +1 for the insight